# How I can access the Create button code that is in the header of a view?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to access the create button code that is in the header of the tree view of the model stock.picking .
Is it possible to do this?
Maybe this is stored in a file within the package Odoo . I dont know

[image]

If any give me the path to access this file.
Please someone tell me how to access the code for this button. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use like:

**V9 New APi**

```
def create(self, vals)
    super(model, self).create(self, vals)
    ---- write your code----
```

**V8**

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    super(model, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
    ---- write your code---
```

-
if create button pressed then you want something so you can use **fields_view_get** method and override.

Comment: This will be triggered only after the new item is saved, not immediately after the "Create" button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In the addons folder,go to web module->static->src->js and find the file `view_list` once you open the file search for this line `'addable': _lt("Create"),` You can edit this string now and after restarting the server and upgrading the web module you can see your new string instead of Create.